# Read csv file titles with blanc inside

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I'm trying to read a the csv file :

```
"EDP";"Picture 1";"Picture 2";"Picture 2"
"1001480210";"T244.png";"";""
```

I create a script to read this files :

```
cd ~/86829/
while IFS=';' read "EDP" "Picture 1" "Picture 2" "Picture 3"
```

When i run the script, i got this error :

```
./RUN_CopyPictures.sh: 9: read: Picture 1: bad variable name
```

When i change titles to `"Picture1";"Picture2";"Picture2"` , and the script to `while IFS=';' read EDP Picture1 Picture2 Picture3`

it's work

So my question is very clear :

How can i read a title of csv file with blancs inside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about reading "titles" (which is usually just the first line of the CSV file).

Instead, your problem (that causes the error) is that a line `read x` assigns a value to the variable named `x` (which can then be referenced via `$x`).

In your example you use `read "Picture 1"` which effectively tries to assign a value to the variable named `Picture 1`.
Since bash forbids variable names with spaces (just like probably any other non-esoteric programming language), this gives you an error.

The solution is to use legible and legit variable names:

```
while IFS=';' read edp pic1 fusel y
do
   echo "Picture 1 is ${pic1}"
   echo "Picture 2 is ${fusel}"
   echo "Picture 3 is ${y}"
done
```

There are a number of naming-schemes for variable names, common ones include *all lowercase* with (or without) *underscores* to separate words, or *CamelCase*.

#### on "titles"

Your script doesn't know *anything* about what you refer to as "titles".
CSV doesn't know anything about "titles" either. 
CSV is simply a format that has both lines (rows) and colums, as opposed to simpler text files that only have lines.
And just as a text-file doesn't have a notion of a "heading", a CSV file has no "titles".
Popular CSV-exporting software might, however, assign a special meaning to the very first row in a CSV-file and (ab)use it for title-information (so the content is only a label, whereas the actual column-content can be something different)

In any case, the `IFS=';' read ...` part of your script doesn't do *anything* with titles; it simply extracts multiple fields from a single line if input data and assigns these fields to variables.
The name of these variables can be totally arbitrary (as long as they conform to the bash syntax for variable names), and need not have anything to do with the content of the file.

Comment: hello http://stackoverflow.com/users/1169096/uml%c3%a4ute thanks for your clear response , but the csv file is a generated file with thos titles, i cant change it , i must work with't with the titles "Picture 1" ... , so any other solution ?

Comment: the variable names are totally unrelated to what you call "titles". they could be called "x" or "furdelmurdel" and still display the nth column.